# Load a jar using symbolic link in the class-path manifest attribute for a jar

Tags: java, jar, manifest, symlink

If I have a symbolic link to a jar file in a directory structure like such

`foo 
  |
   lib
      /bar.jar--------------------------------
                                             |
                                              bar
                                                 /bar.jar`

Where `bar.jar` in `foo/lib` is a symbolic link to `bar.jar` in the bar directory. Can I have my manifest class-path attribute be like such `Class-Path: lib/bar.jar` and use the symbolic link  of `lib/bar.jar` to load `bar/bar.jar` or is the manifest classpath attribute for a jar unable to handle symbolic links?

Comment: I think symlink of bar/bar.jar is enough to execute.

Comment: thanks, have you ever tried it before?

Comment: I tried after you questioned.. :)